# Scan a directory tree and reading .csv files into a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, directory-structure, os.walk

I am trying to walk a directory tree and for each csv encountered on the walk I would like to open the file and read columns 0 and 15 into a data-frame (after which I'll process and move onto the next file.  I can walk the directory tree using the following:

```
rootdir = r'C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Alco/auditopt/'
for dirName,sundirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
         print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
         for fname in fileList:
             print('\t%s' % fname)
             df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=1, usecols=[0,15],parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['date', 'total_pnl_per_pos'])
             print(df)
```

but I'm getting the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'auditopt.os-pnl.BBG_XASX_ARB_S-BBG_XTKS_7240_S.csv' does not exist.
```

I am trying to read files which do exist. They are in an MS Excel .csv format so I don't know if that is an issue - if it is, would someone let me know how I read an MS Excel .csv into a data-frame please.

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
Found directory: C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Alco/auditopt/
Found directory: C:/Users/stacey/Documents/Alco/auditopt/roll_597_oe_2017-03-10
        tradeopt.os-pnl.BBG_XASX_ARB_S-BBG_XTKS_7240_S.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-3753e367432d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/stacey/Documents/scripts/Pair_Results_Code_1.0.py', wdir='C:/Users/stacey/Documents/scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Documents/scripts/Pair_Results_Code_1.0.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/stacey/Documents/scripts/Pair_Results_Code_1.0.py", line 36, in main
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=1, usecols=[0,15],parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['date', 'total_pnl_per_pos'])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8449)

FileNotFoundError: File b'tradeopt.os-pnl.BBG_XASX_ARB_S-BBG_XTKS_7240_S.csv' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading in the file, you need to provide the full path. `os.walk` by default does not supply the full path. You'll need to supply it yourself.

Use `os.path.join` to make this easy.

```
import os
full_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, ...)
```